# Can't seem to use a variable as the index of a multi-value parameter

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, report, builder

I'm trying to write a custom function in Report Builder 3.0 that basically checks the values in a multi-value Parameter (they'll be 1, 2, or 3) and returns either "Bronze" (1), "Silver" (2) or "Gold" (3) depending on what the highest each row is. So...

```
Public Function BronzeSilverGold() As String
    Dim bronzeFlag As Integer = 0
    Dim silverFlag As Integer = 0
    Dim goldFlag As Integer = 0
    Dim numPledges As Integer = Report.Parameters!PledgeValues.Count()

    For index As Integer = 1 To numPledges
        If Report.Parameters!PledgeValues.Value(index) = 1 Then
            bronzeFlag += 1
        ElseIf Report.Parameters!PledgeValues.Value(index) = 2 Then
        bronzeFlag += 1
            silverFlag += 1
        ElseIf Report.Parameters!PledgeValues.Value(index) = 3 Then
            bronzeFlag += 1
            silverFlag  += 1
            goldFlag += 1
        End If
    Next index

    If goldFlag = numPledges Then
        Return "Gold"
    ElseIf silverFlag = numPledges Then
        Return "Silver"
    ElseIf bronzeFlag = numPledges Then
        Return "Bronze"
    End If
End Function
```

The bit that's vexing me is that when I run the report the cell just returns #Error. The problem seems to specifically be the "Report.Parameters!PledgeValues.Value(index)". If I run this:

```
Public Function BronzeSilverGold() As String
    Dim bronzeFlag As Integer = 0
    Dim numPledges As Integer = Report.Parameters!PledgeValues.Count()
    Dim index as Integer = 0

    For index = 1 To numPledges
        If (Report.Parameters!PledgeValues.Value(1) = 2) Then
            bronzeFlag += 1
        End If
    Next index

    return bronzeFlag

End Function
```

Then it successfully returns the value 8 (since the first value in the parameter is a 2). If I change line 7 from Report.Parameters!PledgeValues.Value(1) to Report.Parameters!PledgeValues.Value(index) the cell in the report returns #Error

No idea what I'm doing wrong - if anyone has any idea's they'd be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the [multivalue parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337292%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) value collection is zero-based, not one-based. That is, the first item in the array is index `0` and the last is `Count - 1`. Consequently `For index As Integer = 1 To numPledges` throws an array out of bounds error.

You need to use:

```
For index As Integer = 0 To numPledges - 1
```

As an aside, `Count` is a property not a method so it should not have the brackets after it.